# Overheats to 99 C and shuts down during the update

Tags: updates, lubuntu, overheating

I'd like to update Lubuntu from 11.04 to 11.10.

I installed **lm-sensors** and see that it goes to 99.0 C during the update, and then the laptop shuts down. (crit = +100.0 C)

The bottom of the laptop becomes generally hot, while the areas around the fan and around the CD player stay relatively cool.

Comment: Your computer obviously have a problem, but what is the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **REALLY** suggest you do a very thorough clean of the inside of the laptop and add a cooling system to it. It might as well be that lm-sensors is detecting that and Ubuntu just to make sure the whole place does not get on fire it shuts the laptop off. Would be good if you could add if the laptops air ventilations are clean, how old is the laptop, what other OS systems you have tested there and what video card you have (model of laptop also). But in general a temperature that high just means the laptop is calling for help to get clean.

Comment: I opened the bottom cover, blew some air, and wiped inside the fan. It still seemed to be clean because I cleaned it a month ago. Then I had an idea to update it without the bottom cover. Though at one point it climbed to 96 C, mostly it stayed around 50 C. So the update is complete.

Comment: So basically it needed additional ventilation then?